# how to run a scrapy crawler from another folder in Debian

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I use **Python Scrapy** in **Debian**, i have a PHP script for run my spider.
my php script is  in the project’s top level directory

```
<?php 
$cp = $argv[1];
shell_exec('scrapy crawl mySpider -a  idcrawl="'.$cp.'" ');
 ?>
```

but i just can run it when i am in the top level directory, how should i change my code if i want to run my spider from another folder?
i think that i should change something in `_init file` but i don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `chdir` to change my directory and go to top level  directory.